# Find and Replace columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to write a VBA subroutine where we have 2 inputs

The first column is the current value and the second column is the value I want to replace it with.

The issue I am running into is that it is not doing it for all of my worksheets just the one I am doing it on.

Where should I proceed?

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First you should post the code, so we can help.  Without the code how can we know where it faults?

Comment: Sub MultiFindNReplace()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
    InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: First dim a Worksheet variable. Then, wrap your current code in a `For` loop that works with `i = 1 to worksheets.count`, then inside the loop set `wks=worksheets(i)`. That should work, I need to see your code to help you further,

Comment: Updated with the code, sorry new to SO. The whole thing I wanna do is just have two columns one with find and one with replace. When it takes those inputs it'll update the entire workbook

Comment: If your code depends on the user selecting the input and output ranges, how do you expect it to work on several sheets? is the data structured exactly the same in all sheets and will always work with the same number of rows, or will the user select the used ranges for each sheet?

Comment: @Josh What data exactly are you trying to change with the new values? One column in one sheet? Multiple column in one sheet? One column in multiple sheets? Please be specific.

Comment: They are just Strings. Like Colum A would say Josh and Coloum B would say Tim. I want a macro that would replace all instances of Josh in the workbook with Tim. I want to select a range A2:A94 and replace all those with B2:B94.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at a search for "for each worksheet in workbook"?  This might do it.

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
         InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, your code is not really at all going to address your need, since you want to programatically select your range.  This code will work if all of your "search" columns are column "B":

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ReplaceRng As Range
Dim colNum as Int

colNum = 2 '2 = B

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    'Sets the range from row 2 of the selected column to the last available row in the same column
    Set ReplaceRng = Range(Cells(2, colNum), Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp))
    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
         InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So this didn't seem to work. What I'm trying to do is just take one coloum as the find, and one coloum as replace, and the goal is replace every instance of the find coloum with the replace colum.

Comment: The failing with your code is that you are requesting a user input.  If you want to set that individually per sheet then you need a user input per sheet.  But this doesn't seem to be what you would really want.  The thing you need to address: is it the same column on every sheet, or not?